# fluentd の in_http プラグインで、elasticsearch に bulkAPI で大量のデータ登録を行いたい

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

fluentd の in_http プラグインを利用して、
json ファイルを送り、elasticsearch に登録したいと考えております。

現状、以下のような json ファイルを扱おうとしています。

```
{
    "user_id" : 0,
    "time" : 0,
    "data" : [
        {
            "data0" : 0.0,
            "data1" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "data0" : 0.0,
            "data1" : 0.2
        }
    ]
}
```

1つのデータとしては無事登録されることを確認できました。

ただ、"data" 配列の各要素はそれぞれ別のidとして登録したいので、
bulkAPI を利用できるように、

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : <index_name>, "_type" : <type_name>, "_id" : <id> } }
{ "user_id" : 0, "time" : 0, "data" : { "data0" : 0.0, "data1" : 0.1 } }
{ "index" : { "_index" : <index_name>, "_type" : <type_name>, "_id" : <id> } }
{ "user_id" : 0, "time" : 0, "data" : { "data0" : 0.0, "data1" : 0.2 } }
```

のような形に変換して elasticsearch に投げる方法を検討しています。

その実装について、
・index_name/type_name を http の POST で fluentd に渡す方法
・bulkAPI 形式に fluentd 上で変換する方法
が分からず困っている状態です。

fluentd-elasticsearch で bulkAPI 形式で登録する手順について、
良い方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示頂きたく思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。
　
　
なお、各種バージョンは以下のとおりです。
OS : CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
td-agent : 2.3.6
elasticsearch : 5.5.3

Answer (score 0):

[fluent-plguin-elasticsearch](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch) を使ってください。

in_http はFluentdがHTTPリクエストを受けられるようにするものなので用途が異なります。